# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_exceptions', Python3

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

Iam trying to connect oracle DB using 'cx_Oracle' module. Below is the code i used to connect the db

```
import cx_Oracle
dbConnect_host= cx_Oracle.makedsn('mylocalhost','myportnumber',sid='orcl')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect('system', 'mypassword',dbConnect_host)
print(conn)
c = conn.cursor()
print(e)
```

I am getting following errror

```
File "C:\my_Vnenv\lib\site-packages\cx_Oracle\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from custom_exceptions import Warning, Error, InterfaceError, DatabaseError, DataError, OperationalError, IntegrityError, InternalError, ProgrammingError, NotSupportedError
#ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'custom_exceptions'
```

### Configuration Details

Python 3: Using Python Launcher and IDE used in Pycharm
x_Oracle': Using pip install over through the project interpreter: Version:7.3.0

How to resolve this kind of issue? Appreciate if anyone can help on this?

Thanks

Comment: Update your question and give details about how you installed Python and cx_Oracle, and what versions.

Comment: Hi @ChristopherJones i have updated the question with the configuration details. Please let me know what else would be require

Comment: Since cx_Oracle is built with C the fact that you are importing cx_Oracle/__init__.py means you are using a wrapper of some kind.

Comment: so what would be solution in order to connect the Oracle DB from python?

Comment: You probably have too many unnecessary packages installed with the environment. Try to remove all the packages except cx-oracle. This solved my problem with the error.